# 2.8 - selecting object in collections?

Tags: outliner, collections

I'm brand new to Blender so go easy.. lol

It seems the right click menu is a new concept in 2.8 and I scoured the net and couldn't quite find the solution to what I am looking for.

I am currently going through a very intensive beginners course in Blender 2.8 and my objects are starting to stack up in the Outliner/Collections.

**My question (perhaps wish list?) is this**:
Is there a way to first left click/select an object in the viewport and have it become highlighted in the Outliner?

I hate to draw parallels to Adobe products but I am so used to Photoshop etc... and anytime you select something it always highlights in the Layers Panel, know what I mean? lol

Thank you for listening, I hope this was semi-clear in explanation.
:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is synchronized selection between the outliner and the 3D View.

It is called "[Sync Selection](https://developer.blender.org/T63988)" and is default behavior for the Blender 2.81, I don't think it is available in previous versions, as far as I know.

You can toggle it on or off from the outliner *Filter* popover.
[image]

Comment: Nice, I am happy to know others felt the same way about a feature that is pretty much a given in most apps out there and addressing to solve it. Brilliant!

I'm not sure if I should "go experimental" (as the blender website says) about the future alpha/beta builds, I am still coming to terms with 2.8 release. Thank you Duarte for answer,